# how to interact with database of a website in iphone application

Tags: iphone

I want to add signup and login features to my iPhone web application.

The user will register himself/herself to the website and his/her data will be stored in a database.

Does anyone have any ideas or any tutorial links for it?

I have just work on RSS application so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best shot is ussing HTTP protocol for it.

You need two things:

1. Server Side HTTP enabled application that will connect to database. You can use PHP, ASP.NET, Java Servlets and JSP, Ruby on Rails, Python Django or any other web technology.
2. Your iPhone client that will use HTTP request to send information to your server

So you will send requests from your iPhone APP such as:

```
https://www.yourappserver.com/Login?user=uname&pass=pass
```

And you will receive that request in your Application Server and process it accordingly.

You can to something similar for registering.